# Triangle Square Inscribing

Tags: geometry

I'm reading van Lamoen, Floor and Weisstein's article [Triangle Square Inscribing](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleSquareInscribing.html) from the MathWorld site and reached some hurdles I can't jump over. Specifically,

1. In the first sentence, they mention two types of squares inscribing a triangle--type I has "two adjacent vertices of the square on one side" and type II has "two opposite vertices on one side." I can't come up with an example of a type II.
2. In the next paragraph, it is written, "These squares, however, are not necessarily the *largest* inscribed squares." I don't know what is meant by *largest* in this context. Ratio of the square's area to triangle's area?
3. In that same paragraph but a few lines earlier, one of the steps in the construction says to "construct $FK$". Why? It seems irrelevant--or am I overlooking something?
4. Fourth paragraph from the bottom, we read, "A similar construction can be done by initially erecting a square internally on the side $BC$." Does this method produce an *triangle inscribed square*? I'm having trouble reproducing the steps of the first construction with an internally erected square and the figures don't help at all. (For one, they're too small.)

Comment: They are not looking at *inscribed* squares, but at squares whose vertices are on the *lines* (not necessarily line segments) determined by the vertices of the triangle.